# How do i count the number of letter swaps made to the string?

Tags: java, string, swap

i want my program to count the number of swaps of chars occured to arrange them in alphabetical order. is there any simple way to do this? here is my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrangingBooks{
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
     String str = scan.nextLine();
     char c[] = str.toCharArray();
     Arrays.sort(c);
     System.out.println(new String(c));

     scan.close();
}
}
```

Sample Input =
LLSLM

Output for Sample Input =
2

Comment: It depends on your sorting algorithm. Are you swapping characters that are adjacent to each other or swapping any two characters in the string?

Comment: swapping them in alphabetical order. A-Z

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to write your own sort routine and count the swaps yourself.

Comment: Does your technique provide alphabetical order? Maybe try, "aAbC"?

Comment: If you can sort the array in alphabetical order, then you have 2 arrays with the same elements. You can count the number of swaps required to get 1 array to become the other array. It won't necessarily be the swaps the sorting algorithm used.

Comment: I would agree with Jim Garrison, how about using a selection sort algorythm and just increment a counter each time the while loop, well... loops.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.sort` would choose the most optimal sorting algorithm but you would not be able to track the steps unless you modify the Arrays package.

Alternatively, you can implement your own sort code, or copy/paste one from online and add an Integer counter to increment for every sort-loop iteration. Then you would be able to get the number of steps per input.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2-dimensional `array` to store each `codePoint` and its `index`. Then you can sort the `array` comparing the `codePoints`:

```
public static int countSortedSwaps(String str) {
    int[] arr = str.codePoints().toArray();
    int size = arr.length;
    
    int[][] charIndices = IntStream.range(0, size).boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> arr[i]))
            .map(i -> new int[] {arr[i], i})
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
   
    boolean[] swp = new boolean[size];
    
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            .filter(i -> swp[i] != true && charIndices[i][1] != i)
            .map(i -> count(charIndices, swp, i)).sum();
}

private static int count(int[][] charIndices, boolean[] swp, int index) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = index;
    while (swp[i] == false) {
        swp[i] = true;
        count++;
        i = charIndices[i][1];
    }
    return (count - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious, so I implemented a way to count swaps to get from one array to another.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CountSwaps{
    static int countSwaps( char[] original, char[] sorted){
        int swaps = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<original.length; i++){
            if(original[i] != sorted[i]){
                for(int j = i+1; j<original.length; j++){
                    if(original[i] == sorted[j]){
                        sorted[j] = sorted[i];
                        sorted[i] = original[i];
                        swaps++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        return swaps;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String obj = args[0].toLowerCase();
        char[] original = obj.toCharArray();
        char[] sorted = obj.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sorted);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
        System.out.println(countSwaps(original, sorted));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
    }

}
```

Then we can run it

```
java CountSwaps.java TheQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheTwoLazyDogs
```

> [a, b, c, d, d, e, e, e, e, f, g, h, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, o, o, o, o, p, q, r, r, s, t, t, t, u, u, v, w, w, x, y, z]
> 35
> [t, h, e, q, u, i, c, k, b, r, o, w, n, f, o, x, j, u, m, p, e, d, o, v, e, r, t, h, e, t, w, o, l, a, z, y, d, o, g, s]
> [t, h, e, q, u, i, c, k, b, r, o, w, n, f, o, x, j, u, m, p, e, d, o, v, e, r, t, h, e, t, w, o, l, a, z, y, d, o, g, s]

It took 35 swaps to transform the sorted array back to the original array.
This doesn't reflect the number of swaps taken by the sorting algorithm used.
It also isn't optimal. For example it takes  37 swaps to go the other way, if it was optimal it would be symmetric.